# Why an empty field when creating a new dnn module?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

[image]

But the file is in the application View.ascx

[image]

Help please. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Explain your problem first please, include code snippets instead of hard to see screenshots. state what the screenshots show (first one anyway) and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want to add a module. But when filling out form  Resourse empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any ASCX files in the Folder that you have selected? I would confirm the location of the ASCX files for your module, and then be sure to choose the Proper Owner Folder/Module Folder options in the dropdown lists above that "empty" field.